# jmeter cookie deletion issue programmatically

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I am trying to clear cookies programmatically using the following code. But it is completely removing cookies and acting as "no cookies" from the second iteration. I want to store the cookies for the current iteration and from the next iteration, it should start as fresh again. Can you suggest any modifications here?

My requirement is just to delete cookies after every iteration. HTTP cookie manager is not working(i tried at both test plan and thread group level). So trying programatically.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3;
CookieManager manager = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getCookieManager();
for (int i = 0; i <= manager.getCookieCount(); i++) 
{
     manager.clear();
     ctx.getCurrentSampler().setCookieManager(manager);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code won't compile due to extra `}`
2. Depending on the context `ctx.getCurrentSampler()` may refer to **any** sampler and `getCookieManager()` function will return something only for [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and only if it is in [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) of a HTTP Cookie Manager

In general the official and the best way to clear cookies on each iteration is:

1. Either unticking `Same user on each iteration` box on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level

   [image]
2. Or ticking `Clear cookies each iteration` on HTTP Cookie Manager level

   [image]

Both options assume iterations of the **Thread Group**, anything else (iterations coming from a Loop Controller or While Controller) will be ignored. If this is your use case - add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the very first HTTP Request sampler and use just this one-liner:

```
sampler.getCookieManager().clear()
```

Comment: Hi Dimitry, sampler.getCookieManager().clear() is acting as "no cookies". As you put, i have modified my first request with preprocessor. so it is not working